# NSUnknownKeyException on xib

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new at iOS programming. This is my problem, I have a project in XCode with a single view. I add a new xib with a class named news, now I want to load a web link in a `UIWebView` in this second xib named *news.xib*, but when I run project, receive this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<ViewController 0x752f950> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webpubblicita.'

My code is as follows:

This is **news.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface news : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webpubblicita;
 @end
```

This is **news.m**

```
#import "news.h"
@interface news ()
@end

@implementation news
@synthesize webpubblicita;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //indirizzo web da caricare
    NSString *indirizzo = @"http://www.mmm.com";
    //crea un oggetto URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:indirizzo];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // visualizza la pagina nella UIWebView
    [webpubblicita loadRequest:requestObj];
}
@end
```

Comment: format your code with 4 spaces.

Comment: you need to check your storyboard especially the connection to the webpubblicita outlet.

Comment: mark a breakpoint, that will help you. And have a try with making webpubb as strong.

Comment: Please start using CamelCase for class names :).

Comment: Making the property strong would not solve the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the error again:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<**ViewController** 0x752f950> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webpubblicita.'

You see that the class `ViewController` is loaded, not the `news` class. I think you have specified an incorrect custom class in your Storyboard.